# Elastic search AND operator not woking

Tags: elasticsearch

If I run below query having `AND` it returns nothing:

```
TF1:"rohan sharma" AND TF3:"gaurav"
```

but if I use `OR` its returns result:

```
TF1:"rohan sharma" OR TF3:"gaurav"
```

both data is available

Here is mapping:

```
{
  "TEST": {
    "mappings": {
      "indextestField1": {
        "_ttl": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "TF1": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "TF2": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my java code

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("TEST")
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString("TF1:\"rohan sharma\" AND TF2:\"milind bagal\""))
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

Comment: Instead of changing to an `OR` operator, try running each clause separately, and make sure the document you are looking for comes up for both.  That is, try `"TF1:\"rohan sharma\""` and `"TF2:\"milind bagal\""` as your query string, make sure the document you are looking for comes up for *both* of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping must be wrong, add your analyzer to the fields `TF1` and `TF3`.

```
{
  "TEST": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "TF1": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "TF2": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**References,**

[hack on elasticsearch (3 hrs)](http://prayagupd-dreamspace.blogspot.com/2013/10/first-night-hack-on-elasticsearch.html)

[Scripts example](https://github.com/prayagupd/gccount/blob/master/gccount-analytics/scripts/customer_create_mapping.sh)

Answer (score 0):

About the command you provided, you double-quoted the `"rohan sharma"`, which means the positions of the two words must be located in order.

And I guess the document you want to find, these two words `"rohan sharma"` are not next to each other, which means this condition failed and it results in not-match using the AND operator.

So if you don't need the positional criteria, don't use double-quotes and just use:

`TF1:rohan AND TF1:sharma AND TF3:gaurav`

It's just my assumption. For more detailed answer, you might need to provide the document you want to find using the command you provides.